# Issue when "sliding open" JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have an effect for my JFrame that when it starts it slowly slides the frame open, and when it ends it slowly slides it closed. 
Here is a video of this (recording is in low fps sorry):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v19xtnxc6utt9y3/2019-01-03%2022-17-26.mp4?dl=0
Notice how it closes fine, but when opening it hits the first few pixels then freezes and then opens entirely.

This is my code used to open:

```
    while (frame.getWidth() < MAX_FRAME_WIDTH) {
        frame.setSize(frame.getWidth() + 2, frame.getHeight());
    }
```

And this is the code used to close:

```
    while (frame.getWidth() > 0) {
        frame.setSize(frame.getWidth() - 2, frame.getHeight());
    }
```

If anyone can show me why this issue is present and how to fix it that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use a `Swing Timer` for the animation, not a while loop. The size of the frame changes too fast so you only see the final result. The Timer will allow you to schedule the animation so you can see each step. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) filed :

```
private final Timer timer;
```

And see the effect by:

```
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(0, getHeight());
timer = new Timer(5, open());
timer.start();
```

Where `open()` is defined by :

```
private ActionListener open() {

    return e ->{

        setSize(frame.getWidth() + 2, frame.getHeight());
        if(frame.getWidth() >= MAX_FRAME_WIDTH) {
            timer.stop();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Ok I just played arround and found that adding 
        Thread.sleep(1);

fixes the issue. I guess it was changing the size of the frame faster than swing could update.

Comment: (1-) Don't use Thread.sleep. Updates to Swing components should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). That is why you should be using a Swing Timer. Agreed it many not cause a problem in this simple example, but animation should be done using a Timer, not Thread.sleep(). Take the time to learn how to use Swing the way it was designed to be used.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will look into it. I am quite new to Java so this is very helpful.